# SQL: How to display a particular value in a result if the value in a column does not meet your condition?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am new to SQL and came across a problem that I hope you can help.

Q: Use the UNION operator to generate a result set consisting of two columns from the Vendor table: VendorName and VendorState.  If the vendor is in California, the VendorState value should be "CA"; otherwise, the VendorState value should be "Outside CA".  Sort the final result set by VendorName.

Here's the table: 
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYFDY.png)
So far the I've learned about SELECT, FROM, WHERE, ORDER BY, JOIN, UNION

This is what I have written: 
SELECT VendorName, VendorState
    FROM Vendors
    WHERE VendorState = 'CA' // I know this is wrong
UNION
    SELECT VendorName, VendorState
    FROM Vendors
    //My Condition should be here 'Outside CA'
ORDER BY VendorName;

I like to run an IF Statement here, but not sure about the syntax.  Maybe something like this: 
IF VendorName != 'CA':
   VendorName = 'Outside CA'

Any help you can provide will be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Tuan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CASE WHEN for this: refer to this https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_case.asp

```
SELECT VendorName, case when VendorState='CA' then VendorState else 'Outside CA' end
FROM Vendors


SELECT VendorName, 'CA' as VendorState FROM Vendors where VendorState='CA'
union 
SELECT VendorName, 'Outside CA' as VendorState FROM Vendors where VendorState<>'CA'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The problem asked me to use UNION.  How would I incorporate your solution in a UNION query?

Comment: added in the answer - you can check

Comment: Thanks fa06, it worked.  I tried to vote you up, unfortunately, I am too new to have an effect.  Thanks none-the-less.